# Does cordova LocalFileSystem resolveLocalFileSystemURL return temporary or persistent file entry?

Tags: cordova, filesystems

What is the returning file system type when calling resolveLocalFileSystemURL?

Comment: Check out this link - https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#upgrading-notes It says "For backwards compatibility, the resolveLocalFileSystemURL() method will accept a device-absolute-path, and will return an Entry object corresponding to it, as long as that file exists within either the TEMPORARY or PERSISTENT filesystems."

Comment: What about providing relative path? Will it be resolved as TEMPORARY or PERSISTENT.

Comment: persistent I guess